# How to generate a random IPv6 subnet in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ipv6

I have an existing IPv6 address block. How can I generate a random `/64` network in this block using Python, preferably without using any external libraries?

As an example, you can start from the `fd00::/8` [Unique Local Address (ULA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) block to generate a random private ipv6 network.

Comment: "_As an example, you can start from the fc00::/8 Unique Local Address (ULA) block to generate a random private ipv6 network._" No, the `fc80::/8` blockis reserved. the `fd00::/8` ULA block (has the "L" bit set)  is available for local assignment, but the next 40 bits must be randomly chosen. That gives you a `/48` prefix from which you can use any or all of the 65.536 `/64` networks, and those do not need to be randomly chosen.

Comment: @RonMaupin I edited the question to ask for `fd00::/8` instead. However, I do want a random subnet in this block. So a random prefix + a random subnet in that prefix.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Ron Maupin in their comment on the answer of the OP, here's a solution that uses the correct amount of random bits:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""IPv6 ULA generation."""

from ipaddress import IPv6Network
from random import getrandbits


__all__ = ['get_ula_network']


ULA_BASE = IPv6Network("fd00::/8")


def get_ula_network() -> IPv6Network:
    """Generates a random ULA network."""

    random_suffix = getrandbits(40) << 80
    base_address = ULA_BASE.network_address + random_suffix
    return IPv6Network((base_address, 48))
```

You can drive the mentioned `/64` networks with:

```
>>> network = get_ula_network()
>>> subnets = list(network.subnets(new_prefix=64))
>>> len(subnets)
65536
>>>
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer. It only shows how to generate a 48-bit routing prefix, not how to generate a _random_ /64 network in that routing prefix. Can you update your answer to also include how to select a random subnet from this prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the standard `random` and `ipaddress` modules. Short version:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv6Network
import random

ula = IPv6Network("fd00::/8")
random_network = IPv6Network((
    ula.network_address + (random.getrandbits(64 - ula.prefixlen) << 64 ),
    64))
```

Longer version with explanation:

```py
from ipaddress import IPv6Network
import random

# Start from the ula address block
ula = IPv6Network("fd00::/8")

# Get a random bitstring the size of the number of bits we can randomise.
# This is the number of bits reserved for the network (64) minus the number of bits
# already used in the address block we start from (8).
random_bits = random.getrandbits(64 - ula.prefixlen)

# Bitshift those bits 64 times to the left, so the last 64 bits are zero.
random_address_suffix = random_bits << 64

# Add those bits to the network address of the block we start from
# and create a new IPv6 network with the modified address and prefix 64
random_network = IPv6Network((
    ula.network_address + random_address_suffix,
    64))
```

Comment: Actually, you are generating too many random bits. The number of random bits is supposed to be 40, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you can derive 65,536 `/64` networks.